# How to add the object to a collection from another object?

Tags: c#, object, collections

How do I add objects to an ICollection property? Do I need to initialize the ICollection first? If so how?

I have a Class 'foo' that has an `ICollection<bar>` property named 'bar'. I also have a separate Collection of objects containing deserialized excel data. I want to populate the `ICollection<bar> bar` property using this data.

Assuming I have an instance of `foo` called 'fooexample' then I am trying to assign a value to the `ICollection<bar> bar` by using 'fooexample.bar.id' but I know that this is syntactically incorrect.

Class foo

```
public class foo 
{     
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<bar> bar { get; set; }
}
```

Class bar

```
public class bar 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; } 
}
```

Adding objects from another object

```
exceldata = ParseDocument.Parse(filestream);
foo fooexample = new foo();
foreach (var object in exceldata)
{
    fooexample.id = object.id;
    fooexample.bar.id = object.bar.id; 
    // <-- how do I do this? if I need to initialize it, how?
}
```

Comment: I need the class bar.id from class foo, so it would be like this in foreach --> fooexample.bar.id = object.bar.id

Comment: No clue what you are asking. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Do you want to group `bar` instances by id and create a `foo` for each group ?

Comment: I edited the question please take a look... I hope it is clear now...

Comment: It would help understanding if we new how `exceldata` is declared.

Comment: "fooexample.bar" is of type ICollection and has no property "id", so what you're writing is syntactically wrong. You could do "fooexample.bar.Add(x)" and - if "object.bar" is of type "bar", it could be "fooexample.bar.Add(object.bar)". This would get you a collection of all exceldata's "bar" properties. If that's what you asking for.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr I mean the fooexample.bar.id is what I am trying to do, to acces the ICollection<bar> bar -> where <bar> has the property "id" on public class bar.

but yeah, It is syntactically wrong because it just shows "fooexample.bar.Add(relatedobject)" which is in this case I am trying to solve, since it cannot convert from 'string' to ICollection bar.

Comment: You need: `public ICollection<bar> bar { get; } = new List<bar>();` and then `fooExample.bar.Add(new bar { id = obj.id, name = obj.bar.name });`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes it doesn't have any red lines when I put it, but when I run the program I got this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: is this really an option? I mean my question or do I just directly get the property from the class and don't mind if there is a ICollection on foo?

like just accessing it directly -> bar.id = obj.id, rather than -> going to fooExample.bar.Add(relatedobject)

Comment: Because you do not intitialize `ICollection<bar> bar`. Change the declaration to `public ICollection<bar> bar { get; } = new List<bar>();` to create a collection. `fooexample.bar.id` does not work, because `fooexample.bar` is a collection. You do have to access item of the collection. E.g.: `fooexample.bar[0].id`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I did initialize it and it is on public...

Comment: but removing "fooExample" made it work...

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the impression you dont actually need a collection so you could do the following.

Class foo

```
public class foo 
{     
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public bar bar { get; set; }
}
```

Adding objects from another object

```
exceldata = ParseDocument.Parse(filestream);
foo fooexample = new foo();
foreach (var object in exceldata)
{
    fooexample.id = object.id;
    fooexample.bar = new bar();
    fooexample.bar.id = object.bar.id;
}
```

There is a shorthand in C# to instantiate an object and set it's properties on one line so you could alternatively have

```
exceldata = ParseDocument.Parse(filestream);
foo fooexample = new foo();
foreach (var object in exceldata)
{
    fooexample.id = object.id;
    fooexample.bar = new bar({id = object.bar.id});
}
```

**Or using a collection**

Class foo

```
public class foo 
{     
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<bar> bar { get; set; }
}
```

Adding objects from another object

```
exceldata = ParseDocument.Parse(filestream);
foo fooexample = new foo();
fooexample.bar = new List<bar>();
foreach (var object in exceldata)
{
    fooexample.id = object.id;
    fooexample.bar.Add(new bar({id = object.bar.id}));
}
```

As others have noted you could alternatively initialize the List in the 'foo' class.